# Parsing HTML from $http response losing href attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parsing

I am having an issue parsing the HTML response of a `$http.get()`.

I can get the raw HTML response and output it as a string to the console:

```
'<html><head><title>portal</title></head><body><H1>portal</H1><hr><pre><A HREF="/WebPortal/">To Parent Directory</A><br><br><A HREF="/WebPortalPI/Brochures/White/">White stuff</A><br><A HREF="/WebPortalPI/Brochures/Green/">Green things</A><br><A HREF="/WebPortalPI/Brochures/Yellow/">Yellow wigits</A><br><A HREF="/WebPortalPI/Brochures/Blue/">Blue Misc</A><br></pre><hr></body></html>'
```

When I parse the HTML using `DOMParser()` and then query for all anchor tags within the pre tag it seems to be losing the `href` attributes. This is a simplified version of what I see in `console.log($scope.data)` at the end of the `$http.get().success()`.

> [a, a, a, a, a, item: function]
>       0: a
>           ...
>           href: ""
>           ...

As you can see in the Fiddle, the `text` data is conveying from the response HTML through the angular/javascript to the main page HTML just fine. Does anyone have any idea why I cannot parse out these `href` attributes for use in my main page?

DEMO:  **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/6yLLdcL0/)**

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="link in data">
    <a href="{{link.href}}">{{link.text}}</a>
</div>
```

*Javascript:*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = [];

    $http.get('/my-api-call').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

      //rather than posting my actual api link (not public yet) this is the data that is returned in the response
      var str = '<html><head><title>portal</title></head><body><H1>portal</H1><hr><pre><A HREF="/WebPortal/">To Parent Directory</A><br><br><A HREF="/WebPortalPI/Brochures/White/">White stuff</A><br><A HREF="/WebPortalPI/Brochures/Green/">Green things</A><br><A HREF="/WebPortalPI/Brochures/Yellow/">Yellow wigits</A><br><A HREF="/WebPortalPI/Brochures/Blue/">Blue Misc</A><br></pre><hr></body></html>';

      var parser = new DOMParser();

      var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

      $scope.data = doc.firstChild.querySelectorAll('pre a');

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      //handle $http error
    });

}]);
```

Comment: The DOMParser can't resolve the URL as it's relative, and the DOMParser has no root to start from. If the URL's are absolute, it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any ability to modify the links in the original HTML. Is there a way to give the DOMParser a context to start from?

Comment: You can try to inject `base` tag into head section of the string. Or simply `str = '<base href="' + location.origin + '">' + str;`. But this is hack.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to pass a root URL into the DOMParser, but you could always use string.replace -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gkpzrp95/**

Comment: Or the old fashion way of using `implementation.createHTMLDocument` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gkpzrp95/1/**

Comment: @adeneo – your `string.replace` idea gave me a new thought on how to handle this. I don't need to transform the `href` into an absolute URL, I can just rename `href` to something like `data-href` (`str.replace(/href/gi, 'data-href');`) and that value will get carried along in the attributes property when parsed. [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/6yLLdcL0/5/)